# RDP connection manager for Mac

Tags: remote-desktop

Does anyone know if there are any RDP connection managers similar to Terminals or Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection Manager for the Mac? I'm aware of Royal TSX but $35 seems a bit steep for an RDP client.

CoRD is my current go-to but it does not allow for organization of connections within folders and is just a big long list. It also ends up always being fuzzy if I don't do full screen with it.

Comment: Royal TSX has Lite for free, which supports 10 connections.

Answer (score 1):

[iTeleport](http://www.iteleportmobile.com/features) manages both VNC and RDP connections, and is available on iOS and Mac, as well as Windows even.

Link to Mac App Store is [here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/iteleport-vnc-rdp/id489094439?mt=12).

If cost is a consideration, try [CoRD](http://cord.sourceforge.net). (EDIT: Missed the fact that this was in the OP. My apologies.)

Other alternatives I've tried include [iTap](http://itap-mobile.com/desktop/rdp) and [Jump Desktop](http://jumpdesktop.com).

Comment: Yea if I was going to pay $30 I'd rather pay the extra $5 for Royal TSX. As I mentioned in my post, I'm using CoRD currently but the limitations for organizing my connections is lacking at best (I have over 200 servers spread out amongst various clients that I need to be able to somehow categorize or place in folders).

Comment: Missed the second part of your post. Sorry about that!

Comment: In lieu of a program to manage your various clients, you could save each as a shortcut to your Mac, and organize them in folders.